# Java swing: Jtable with many models and custom renderer

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable

I have a jtable in which i recolor rows depending on values from model, something like this:

```
resultTable = new javax.swing.JTable(){
    private Border outside = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK);
    private Border inside = new EmptyBorder(0, 1, 0, 1);
    private Border highlight = new CompoundBorder(outside, inside);
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
        //  Color row based on a cell value
        if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
            c.setBackground(getBackground());
            int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            if (getStatus().equals("status1")) {
                myFirstTableModel model = (myFirstTableModel ) resultTable.getModel();                    
                if ((model.getObjectAtRow(modelRow).getMsg().getRegNumIn() == 3)) {
                    c.setBackground(new Color(255, 244, 148));//YELLOW - needs attension
                } 
            } else if (getStatus().equals("status2")) {
                mySecondTableModel model = (mySecondTableModel) resultTable.getModel();

                if (model.getObjectAtRow(modelRow).getMsg().getTask() == 2) {
                    c.setBackground(new Color(210, 245, 176));//GREEN - got attension
                } 
            } 
        } else if (isRowSelected(row)) {
            jc.setBorder(highlight);
            c.setBackground(new Color(201, 204, 196));
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

I set different models to my table (myFirstTableModel, mySecondTableModel) depending on var **status** in SwingWorker thread and display modal dialog with "Please wait".

```
final WaitDialog dialog = new WaitDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
    dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
});
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        setStatus("status2");
        Refresh();
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void done() {
        dialog.dispose();
    }
};

worker.execute();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

changing model in Refresh() method:

```
if (getMainFrameStatus().equals("status2")) {
     @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Update the model here

                    resultTable.setModel(new mySecondTableModel(data));
                }
            });
```

But i think `prepareRendere` is called when wait `dialog` is obfuscating my table. But different model is not applied yet.

And obviously i get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: myFirstTableModel cannot be cast to mySecondTableModel at mySecondTableModel model = (mySecondTableModel) resultTable.getModel();
```

Can i allow table calling `prepareRenderer`?
How do i make this mess work correctly?

Comment: You might want to condense the code somewhat when posting here. For one thing, people don't like to wade through useless information just to help. Also, it might turn out you find the answer that way yourself (happens to me all the time).

Comment: `Refresh()` method is not understandable. Please improve it.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: _always_ type check before the actual cast, especially if you know that there different types ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best not to smear details of the data (business) domain into the view. In you context, you can f.i. achieve a clean separation by

- define an interface which has the notion of Status (needs-attention, had-attention ... )
- let your custom model implement that interface
- in the view, access the status of the model via that interface

something like (uncompiled, just a pseudo-code snippet)

```
public interface StatusAware {

      enum Status {

           NORMAL,
           GOT_ATTENTION,
           NEEDS_ATTENTION,
           ...

      }
      public Status getStatus(int modelIndex);
} 

public class MyFirstTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements StatusAware {

       public Statuc getStatus(int modelRow) {
           boolean needsAttention = getObjectAtRow(modelRow).getMsg().getRegNumIn() == 3;
           return needsAttention ? NEEDS_ATTENTION : NORMAL;
       }

       ....
}


public class MySecondTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements StatusAware {

       public Statuc getStatus(int modelRow) {
           return // the status of the given row
       }

       ....
}

public class MyTable extends JTable { // if you insist on not using JXTable 


      public Component prepareRenderer(...) {
            Component comp = super(...)
            if (getModel() instanceof StatusAware {
                 Status status = ((StatusAware) getModel()).getStatus(convertRowIndexToModel(row));
                 if (NEEDS_ATTENTION == status) {
                       ...
                 } else if (...) {
                      ...
                 } 
            }
            return comp;
       }
}
```

**Edit**

Similar in SwingX (cough ... no tutorial, just the api doc, wiki, snippets, swinglabs-demo):

- implement a custom HighlightPredicate: this decides whether or not a given cell should be visually "decorated". It has just one method to implement, allows read-access to the data via a ComponentAdapter
- configure one of the pre-defined Highlighters (there's a whole bunch) with the predicate
- add the Highlighter to the table

A snippet, taken from the ComponentAdapter api doc

```
     HighlightPredicate feverWarning = new HighlightPredicate() {
         int temperatureColumn = 10;

         public boolean isHighlighted(Component component, ComponentAdapter adapter) {
             return hasFever(adapter.getValue(temperatureColumn));
         }

         private boolean hasFever(Object value) {
             if (!value instanceof Number)
                 return false;
             return ((Number) value).intValue() &gt; 37;
         }
     };

     Highlighter hl = new ColorHighlighter(feverWarning, Color.RED, null);
     table.addHighlighter(hl);
```

**Edit 2**

Accessing data that's not part of the model is not supported directly. Though it lurked around for a while, it never seemed quite important enough to jump for it :) Plus it kind-of violates the base idea: have a common abstraction to access the data without knowing the type of underlying component nor model (the Highlighter/-Predicate and StringValue are exactly the same for table, list, tree).

With that in mind, you can get hold of it indirectly via the adapter's target component:

```
  if (adapter.getComponent() instanceof JTable) {
      JTable table = (JTable) adapter.getComponent();
      TableModel model = table.getModel();
      if (model instanceof MyModel) {
          int modelRow = adapter.convertRowIndexToModel(adapter.row);
          MyObject object = ((MyModel).getRowObjectAt(modelRow));
          ... // check the object
      }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please give a link with tutorial on how configure highlighter for JXTable, so if (table.getValueAt==9) that row colored red. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works! many thanks. But i have one more question. In my tablemodels i use List of objects as data and show in table only certain properties of those objects, and recolored rows depending on some properties that exist in model, but arent displayed, using  method getObjectAtRow(int row). How can i change adapter.getValue(temperatureColumn) to get to the model?

Comment: I think i made it work. Thank you very much for your explanations.

Answer (score 3):

First, you might want to force events to wait till after the model is reloaded by calling

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)
```

around them. Or possibly force the model loading to take precedence. Not quite sure, but

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)
```

might be what you want there.

Secondly, you might want to check out the JXTable from [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net). Specifically, the highlighters may make your life a little easier. In my current project that saved me a bunch of code - which I now don't have to maintain (yay!)

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm a copy past programmer so please bear with me. Could you, please give small example of highlighting row depending on value from model?

Comment: Sorry, but not at this time. Bottom line: I'm too lazy to wade through your code and clean it up and I'm not quite sure what you mean by your question so I can't code something sensible to answer it. I will do either if you clean up either your code example or reformulate your comment above, though. This isn't really meant as harshly as it sounds. Sure I'd help you. But I just don't have the time and inclination to do your work for you from scratch - and I assume I'm not alone in that respect.

Comment: Oh sorry. I dont meant from scratch. I meant a little snippet where HighlighterPipeline is configured the way if cell has "-22" that row colored red. If its 8 - its blue. I cant find any examples on web. Filter with regular expressions is not optimal in my case. I need something like if (table.getValueAt==-22) hl.setBackground(Color.RED);

Comment: Just go to swingx.java.net, hit the LAUNCH button and navigate to the highlighters section. You'll find comprehensive code examples which you can more or less easily adapt to your needs. Only turnoff is that the sample code is cluttered up by the injection system used in the demo application which will not really be useful to you. But... cut&paste programmers have to work, too, by wading through the code and identifying what has to be cut :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I set different models to my table (myFirstTableModel, mySecondTableModel) depending

Then you need different logic in the prepareRenderer(...) code to support both models.

In this case you would probably want 2 different tables. Then instead of changing the model in the table, you would change the table in the viewport of the scrollpane.

Comment: hmm ... no, not really. If at all, it's an artefact of doing _specific_ visual config in prepareRenderer (instead of supporting such in a general manner, as f.i. by Highlighters in SwingX :-)

Answer (score 2):

For row coloring is JXTable of the SwingX project indeed a good suggestion.

Besides that, why do you override this `prepareRenderer` method anyway to alter settings of the component which was created by the renderer in the first place.

For that specific problem, I would change the renderer on the table when I switch the model, and put all that logic in my renderer.

If you do not yet have your own renderer, it is as simple as decorating the default one and applying the code you now have in your `prepareRenderer` on the component returned by the default renderer.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your approach:

- It is clear that, your `JTable` depends on two different implementation of `TableModel`.
- If you follow good design, you will ended up with creating two different implementation of `JTable` and coupling them with your `specific` `TableModel`.

My suggestion is to go for two different implementation on JTable. And change the JTable when you notice the value change of `status`.

---

Other than that, `status` & `model` are two different property and which is requiring synchronization in your case.

So, you need to be aware of, what is needed to be changed in background thread & what on EDT.

Comment: *you will ended up with creating two different implementation of JTable* - no, never: all JSomething are for using, data variations are to be implemented in ... well .. the model.

Comment: @kleopatra if it is `no, never`: already it is violated when it was done `new javax.swing.JTable(){`. Can you deny? Additionally can you deny that, given JTable is coupled to two different table model? But surely it could be improved using TableCellRenderer

Comment: yeah, it already does - but that's no reason to detoriate it even more :-) Custom renderers are an alternative, the problem here is the per-row uniform visual config across all rendering components provided by different renderers: they all have to be aware of the value specifics. BTW, Rob's approach (configure in prepareRenderer) is the same as JXTable - the latter does so very generally by a pluggable Highlighter